# How to avoid blank spaces after a value stored in database taken from textbox, asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

whenever i insert a string value into database from textbox, in asp.net, a random number of blank spaces are stored after the string value in the database row? how to avoid it?

Comment: can you show you code? Extra space will go to database if you put extra space in the text box. The approach should be you should use javascript or jQuery function on client site to prompt user that there is additional space there in the text box.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Trim() Function or you may also want to check your database set up.

If you have used char or nchar, you'll always be allocated the x amount of bytes space, and your string will be padded. To avoid this use varchar which will only store upto the character you sent.

If you send "test"

char(10) will store "test      "

However varchar(10) will store "test"

Comment: Well in that instance I would also suggest stepping through your code to see if the text being sent to the database has the extra spaces and if so where they are coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Check the definition of the column in your database.  Is it CHAR(x) or NCHAR(x)?  Or VARCHAR(x) or NVARCHAR(x)?

If it's not VARCHAR or NVARCHAR, it's a fixed-length field, which means that there will always be spaces after it (assuming the length of your string is not exactly that of the field).

Unless you're coding from scratch, it may be a big deal to change the definition of a field in your database (and changing it won't remove spaces from all the existing rows already there).  But that is *probably* what's happening.

This could also be happening if you're using CHAR(x) or NCHAR(x) somewhere along the way, in a stored procedure parameter or when creating parameters for a SqlCommand.

To trim spaces off a string, I like Habib's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
string content= TextBox1.Text.Trim();
```

Now store this `content` value into database.

If this doesn't help probably the issue is not at your application side.

You may additionally execute this query to remove the spaces-

```
UPDATE
    your_table
SET 
    your_column = TRIM(your_column);
```

This will ensure you remove any spaces in all the values of the column.

Comment: See the updated answer.. You should have mentioned the DBMS you used, the datatype of the columns, etc for allowing people to give answers easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use trim() function in c# or SQL Query side ..
Ex:
String str = " C# ";
Console.WriteLine("Hello{0}World!", str);
string trStr = str.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textbox1.Text.Replace(" ","");
```

Maybe not the cleanest way to do it, but it should work

Comment: If you want to input something like "this is " then this function will do something like this "thisis" which is not right. trim function removes space from starting and end.

Comment: Cool, did not know about the existence of trim until five minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use trim() option if you are using c#.
for example if your have a text string 'name', you can avoid any following blank spaces by :

```
string newstr = name.trim();
```

this will ensure that there are no blank spaces left at end of the string.